# A system is comprised of 3 components, each of which is either “working”, “iﬀy”, or “failed”...

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

Original Problem:

*A system is comprised of 3 components, each of which is either “working”, “iﬀy”, or “failed”. The system will work if any two components are working or if none of the components are failed. Let W be the event that the system is working. Let A be the event that at least one component is iﬀy. 
a). Deﬁne carefully a sample space, S, for this experiment. How many elements does it have? 
b). In terms of your sample space, give the events W, A, and W ∩ A.fa*

I already know that there are 27 elements, but don't understand how did they do part b) for events W?

W = {WWW, WWI, IWW, WIW, IWI, WWF, FWW, WFW, III, WII, IIW}

How come there is no F's in the set? Can someone please explain?

EDIT** What happened to IIF, IFI, FII?

Comment: Recall: *The system will work if any two components are working or if none of the components are failed*. Thus you have all the combinations with two $W$'s, and in addition all the combinations with no $F$'s.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? I see FWW, WFW, WWF in the set.

Comment: I don't get why there is no for example, IIF?

Comment: None of those components are working and it is not the case that none have failed. Notice that III is there because none have failed.

Comment: @Mary : For IIF to be working: two of the components must be working (and actually none is) or none of the components may be failed (and actually the third is).

Comment: Oh, I get it. Because it says "all combinations with no F's," that is why III, WII, IIW works. If we write IIF, IFI, or FII they have a F in it, so it doesn't work. I got confused and thought "iffy" is considered working too. Thank you for the clarification!